# Constructing an upper confidence limit for $σ^2$

Tags: sampling, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval, interval-arithmetic

Suppose that $X_1, ..., X_n$ form a random sample from the normal distribution with unknown mean µ and
unknown standard deviation σ.

Construct an upper confidence limit U(X1, ..., Xn) for $σ^2$ such that

$P[σ^2 < U(X_1, ..., X_n)]= 0.99$.

What I've done is so far

Since $\dfrac {(n-1)s^2}{σ^2}$~ $X^2(n-1)$,

$P(X^2_.99 <\dfrac {(n-1)s^2}{σ^2})$=$P(σ^2<\dfrac {(n-1)s^2}{X^2_.99})$

Therefore $U(X_1, ..., X_n)=\dfrac {(n-1)s^2}{X^2_.99}$

Now is it correctly done?

Comment: Don't forget the mean $\mu$ which is unknown too

Comment: @CharlesMadeline What does μ have to do with this? $\dfrac {(n-1)s^2}{X^2_.99}$ does not contain  μ

Comment: Yes, your answer is perfect.

Comment: Your normal variables need to have mean $0$ for the sum to follow a chi-squared law https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution